Apache configuration for bugzilla and mediawiki on the same server
I have currently installed bugzilla and mediawiki on a VM with the below configuration.
bugzilla.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerName xxxxxxxx
DocumentRoot /var/www/html/bugzilla/

<Directory /var/www/html/bugzilla/>
AddHandler cgi-script .cgi
Options +Indexes +ExecCGI
DirectoryIndex index.cgi
AllowOverride Limit FileInfo Indexes Options AuthConfig
</Directory>

ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error_log
CustomLog /var/log/apache2/access_log common
</VirtualHost>

mediawiki.conf
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerName XXXXXXXXXXX
    DocumentRoot /var/www/mediawiki
    <Directory /var/www/mediawiki>
        AllowOverride all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    # According MWiki Manual:Security
    php_flag register_globals off

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.local.error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/wiki.local.access.log combined

</VirtualHost>

When I access the page bugzilla is opening but mediawiki page is not opening with the error 404 page not found. If I comment out bugzilla conf then mediawiki page is opening without any issue.
Can you please help me with the configuration to resolve both the urls?

What looks really odd is /var/www/html/bugzilla/ versus /var/www/mediawiki ...

/var/www/mediawiki is the path where I have configured mediawiki

Certainly possible, just unexpected.

this is resolved with the help of alias in apache conf file

It is unclear how an Alias directive could resolve the issue you describe. Would you be so kind to post an answer yourself and explain to others finding your question what the exact cause has been (" why?" ) and how the exact solution looks like? Thanks!
